# Incorrect textbox dimensions in html form

Tags: html, css

I am having incorrect dimensions of my textbox in a simple HTML form. As I am trying to add Pincode-city-state validations. I tried to change it , but it is again same. Below is the snippet of my code. Please help me with my code

index.html

````html
```

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=\, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    #pincode{width:21%;}
    .textbox{
        width: 30%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-size: 16px;
        background-position: 10px 10px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
        transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
        margin-left:2%;
    }
    /* CODE */
    .btn{
        font-weight: 400;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-image: none;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        height: 46px;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #5cb85c;
        border-color: #4cae4c;
        margin-left:2%;

    }
    h2{font-family:Arial; font-size:30px; text-align:center;}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div><h2>Get city from Pincode</h2></div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <form autocomplete="off" method="post" id="frmPinCode" style="text-align:center;">
        <div>

        <input type="text" class="textbox" name="pincode" id="pincode" placeholder="Enter Pincode" autocomplete="new-password">
        <input type="button" class="btn" value="Get Details">

</div> 
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>
   <input type="text" class="textbox" id="city" disabled placeholder="City"><br/><br/>
   <input type="text" class="textbox" id="state" disabled placeholder="State">
</div>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>

```
````

Below is the screenshot of how my form looks.

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnTJ1.png)

Answer (score 0):

your css and html has a lot of issues:

try to learn bootstrap it will help you a lot, [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)

notice: you cannot do that `class="textbox" id="pincode"` when you want to give them attributes on CSS, practice more.

CSS:

```
form{
    width:30%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#pincode{width:calc(100% - 120px);}
.textbox{width: 100%;}
.textbox, #pincode{
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
-webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
margin:0;
}
/* CODE */
.btn{
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
border: 2px solid #5cb85c;
padding: 13px;
width:110px;
display:inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
margin-top:-6px;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
color: #fff;
background-color: #5cb85c;
}
h2{font-family:Arial; font-size:30px; text-align:center;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div><h2>Get city from Pincode</h2></div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <form autocomplete="off" method="post" id="frmPinCode">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="pincode" id="pincode" placeholder="Enter Pincode" autocomplete="new-password">
            <input type="button" class="btn" value="Get Details">
        </div> 
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="textbox" id="city" disabled placeholder="City"><br/><br/>
            <input type="text" class="textbox" id="state" disabled placeholder="State">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Learning Bootstrap is a bad practice. Learning CSS basics is key.

Comment: I will try it out.

Comment: @Roy I also mention that

Comment: @SC Good Luck :)